# Styled-components: Styles are not applied when trying to style already styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm trying to style my component which was styled already. But styles in the new rules are not applied in output CSS.

Can I style component that I already styled?

Thanks you in advance for your help.

EDIT: Add rest of LanugageChooser definition

```
// COMPONENT THAT I'M TRYING TO STYLE
const LanguageChooser = () => {
    const Container = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 36px;
        & > div:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    `;

    return (
        <Container>
            <Flag { ...languages.pl }/>
            <Flag { ...languages.en }/>
        </Container>
    )
}

const Flag = ({ flag, language }) => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();

    const Button = styled.div`
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 24px;
        transition: .2s all;
        &:hover {
            font-size: 36px;
        }
    `;

    return (
        <Button onClick={ () => i18n.changeLanguage(language) }>{ flag }</Button>
    )
}
```

```
// TRYING ADD MARGIN LEFT, BUT THERE IS NO RESULT.
// ANY OTHER CSS PROPERTY ARE NOT APPLYING
const Navbar = ({ color }) => {
    ...

    const StyledLanguageChooser = styled(LanguageChooser)`
       margin-left: auto;
    `;

    const Nav = styled.nav`
        display: flex;
        align-content:center;
        background: ${ color };
        padding: 2px 3px;
    `;

    return (
        <Nav className="navbar">
            <StyledNavLink to="/home">...</StyledNavLink>
            <StyledNavLink to="/maps">...</StyledNavLink>
            <StyledNavLink to="/charts">...</StyledNavLink>
            <StyledLanguageChooser/>
        </Nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide your "LanguageChooser" definition?

Comment: I have added LanguageChooser definition. If you want access to all project give me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, move the styled component **outside of function scope** or your style will reset on every render and you will **get heavy performance issues**.

Secondly, in order to apply styles, you need to pass `className` property.

See [Styling normal React components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components)

> If you use the styled(MyComponent) notation and MyComponent does not render the passed-in className prop, then no styles will be applied.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 36px;
  & > div:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
`;
const LanguageChooser = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <Container className={className}>
      <Flag {...languages.pl} />
      <Flag {...languages.en} />
    </Container>
  );
};

const Button = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 0.2s all;
  &:hover {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
`;

const Flag = ({ flag, language }) => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <Button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage(language)}>{flag}</Button>;
};
```